# JMS active mq one message to be consumed concurrently

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I am using apache active mq, and have a common consumer for multiple operations. For every consumer it will take around 15-20 mins for code execution, and I want if in between the another message is produced then both messages should be consumed in parallel though both have one consumer only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In application context where you have defined the DefaultMessageListenerContainer bean, You can add "concurrentConsumers" property and define the number of concurrent consumers you want, to listen to your message Queue.

Below is an example for the same

```
 <bean id="jmsMailContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="concurrentConsumers">
        <value>100</value>
    </property>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="mailDestination"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="jmsMailConsumer"/>
</bean>
```